# XCODE и JSON с ивритом: как заставить читать справа налево?

Tags: json, xcode, rtf

Мне переодически требуется парсить JSON-файлы, в которых встречаются отдельные значения, содержащие слова или строки на иврите.

Однако я столкнулся со следующей проблемой: в самом файле, если открыть его в стороннем редакторе  все отображается правильно, но если копируешь этот же файл в окружение Xcode и открываешь уже в нем (или парсишь), то это же самое слово отображается... слева направо. Кто-нибудь сталкивался с подобным? Как быть?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]